# flot - how to set scale to desired number

Tags: javascript, graph, flot

I had a need to align flot ticks with grid lines (which was solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27941217/2883328),
but now I also have a need to set my scale to a specific "step", such as {`1`, `2`, `5`, `10`, `20`, `50`, `100`} -- a "round whole number".  That number should not be something like `2.59` or `13`, for example, because those are not "round whole numbers".

For example, run and observe flot example below:

- note that the left scale is set amicably via some internal flot algorithm.
- the right axis is set to match ticks with the left scale via `alignTicksWithAxis` option, but it does not scale so amicably.  Namely, the scale factor is 13 in the specific case below, and is data-dependent.  I need the scale factor to be one of the above numbers {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, etc} and the graph still fitting on the grid.

How?

[API](https://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) talks about `tickSize` and `minTickSize` but they do not seem to help, presumably because once `alignTicksWithAxis` is on, those get turned off.  Ideally I think the tickSize of 20 will work best for my purposes of this example.

```js
$(function() {
    flotOptions = {

        "xaxis" : {
            "min" : 20,
            "max" : 63,

        },
        "yaxes" : [ {
            "position" : "left",
            "min" : 0,
            "max" : 15
        }, {
            "position" : "right",
            "min" : 0,
            "max" : 75,
            "alignTicksWithAxis" : 1
        } ],
        "colors" : [ "#EAA433", "#32A2FA"],

    };

    flotData = [
            {
                "data" : [ [ 20.61, 12.52 ], [ 27.82, 12.35 ], [ 35.04, 11.89 ], [ 42.25, 11.19 ], [ 49.47, 10.28 ], [ 56.68, 9.176 ], [ 62.09, 8.246 ], [ 61.84, 8.289 ] ],
                "yaxis" : 1
            },
            {
                "data" : [ [ 20.61, 59.37 ], [ 27.82, 66.57 ], [ 35.04, 70.58 ], [ 42.25, 71.79 ], [ 49.47, 70.59 ], [ 56.68, 67.36 ], [ 62.09, 63.83 ], [ 61.84, 64.00 ] ],
                "yaxis" : 2,
            },
            {
                "data" : [ [ 20.61, 20.61 ], [ 28.85, 28.85 ], [ 37.10, 37.10 ],  [ 45.34, 45.34 ],[ 53.59, 53.59 ],  [ 61.83, 61.83 ] ],

            } ];

    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), flotData, flotOptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<h1>Flot Examples</h1>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
```

From API:

> If you set "alignTicksWithAxis" to the number of another axis, e.g.
>   alignTicksWithAxis: 1, Flot will ensure that the autogenerated ticks
>   of this axis are aligned with the ticks of the other axis. This may
>   improve the looks, e.g. if you have one y axis to the left and one to
>   the right, because the grid lines will then match the ticks in both
>   ends. The trade-off is that the **forced ticks won't necessarily be at
>   natural places**.

Well, assuming I can control the scale's maximum, I can force forced ticks to be at more natural places, but how can I control that not knowing natural tickSize for scale #1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define matching axis notches from existing "step list"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285412/how-to-define-matching-axis-notches-from-existing-step-list)

Answer (score 0):

The tick distance for the right axis is 12.5 (not 13), but it gets rounded.
You can change the display with `"tickDecimals" : 1` (see code snippet at the bottom).
Btw, your left axis also has no whole round number tick distance (2.5).

For a general solution you have to check the maximum value for both data series and then set the axes maximum values and tick numbers yourself or even set a fixed tick array to fully control the tick generation.

Something like

```
if (maxValue <= 5.0) {
    tickSize = 1;
}
else if (maxValue <= 10.0) {
    tickSize = 2;
}
else if ... {
    ...
}
tickNumber = 5;
axisMaximum = tickNumber * tickSize;
```

```js
$(function() {
    flotOptions = {

        "xaxis" : {
            "min" : 20,
            "max" : 63,

        },
        "yaxes" : [ {
            "position" : "left",
            "min" : 0,
            "max" : 15
        }, {
            "position" : "right",
            "min" : 0,
            "max" : 75,
            "alignTicksWithAxis" : 1,
            "tickDecimals" : 1
        } ],
        "colors" : [ "#EAA433", "#32A2FA"],

    };

    flotData = [
            {
                "data" : [ [ 20.61, 12.52 ], [ 27.82, 12.35 ], [ 35.04, 11.89 ], [ 42.25, 11.19 ], [ 49.47, 10.28 ], [ 56.68, 9.176 ], [ 62.09, 8.246 ], [ 61.84, 8.289 ] ],
                "yaxis" : 1
            },
            {
                "data" : [ [ 20.61, 59.37 ], [ 27.82, 66.57 ], [ 35.04, 70.58 ], [ 42.25, 71.79 ], [ 49.47, 70.59 ], [ 56.68, 67.36 ], [ 62.09, 63.83 ], [ 61.84, 64.00 ] ],
                "yaxis" : 2,
            },
            {
                "data" : [ [ 20.61, 20.61 ], [ 28.85, 28.85 ], [ 37.10, 37.10 ],  [ 45.34, 45.34 ],[ 53.59, 53.59 ],  [ 61.83, 61.83 ] ],

            } ];

    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), flotData, flotOptions);
});
```

```html
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<h1>Flot Examples</h1>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
```